# How to detect JSON support in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I tried to detect JSON support with `if(JSON.parse) {}` but it doesn't works. Is there any way to detect the JSON support?

Comment: Do you mean in a specific library or javascript itself? JSON is just a notation for javascript objects, javascript itself supports it natively.

Comment: @websymphony, but it doesn't have the ability to *parse* natively, e.g, create an object given a string.

Comment: Have u tried with if( 'JSON' in window )?

Comment: @websymphony no. I want to detect, if I can use JSON.parse function, or not.

Comment: I think he means if the JSON parser is present. Older versions of IE didn't have it (and there was at least a version of IE that had a buggy implementation)

Comment: @stecb thanks, `if( 'JSON' in window )` works ;-)

Comment: Note: JSON may actually be unavailable in IE10+ if the browser is running in compatibility mode: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manish_ahuja/archive/2013/05/16/ie-10-html5-and-jquery-javascript-runtime-error-json-is-undefined.aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Taken from the json most famous implementation https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

```
var JSON;
if (JSON && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') {
    ....
}
```

(I have merged the two `if`: `if (!JSON) {` of line 163 and `if (typeof JSON.parse !== 'function') {` of line 406.

The trick here is that the `var JSON` will get the value of the JSON object of the browser, `undefined` if not.

Note that in the [latest](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/43d7836c8ec9b31a02a31ae0c400bdae04d3650d/json2.js) version of the library they changed the code to something like:

```
if (typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') {
    ....
}
```

(without pre-declaring the `var JSON`)

Comment: HOw can you check `if (JSON...)` ?? **youll get an error** . its like doing `if (lalala...) //error`. The correct way is  : `if (typeof JSON==="undefined" ...)`

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are right... I had forgotten a line of code... Before the `if` there should be a `var JSON;` . I have even added the "newer" version of the check.

Answer (score 0):

Might not exactly count as an answer to what was asked, but would perhaps parsing the user agent (navigator) and checking for versions you are confident support the parser be a possible alternative?

Comment: There are so many possible user agent that this is not practical. It is difficult to keep up to date. There is a long history of bugs with this kind of user-agent detection, and there are usually better solutions (feature-detection).