# Web pages not loading correctly: '"JSON" is undefined' error

Tags: javascript, c#

I have use a web browser for my project and I made it load a web page as soon as the program has loaded.
Before I have an error called a script error but i used the code 
`webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`
now that error doesn't appear no more but i'm still getting the problem with the loading of a web page

I attached pictures below on what i'm having issue with.

[Here is what the website i was to load looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R0GT.png)

[Here is The Problem i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMC5n.png)

Is there a fix or an addon to visual studios to use a different web browser

Comment: Disconnecting the "check engine" light won't stop your engine from overheating...

Comment: How will I fix them don't know what causing them

Comment: Sorry What are you on about "check engine " light ?

Comment: It's a metaphor. Anyway, if you don't suppress the errors, does the browser tell you what the errors are? Check the dev console.

Comment: I get this error [Click me](http://imgur.com/8KXVhP3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6 WebBrowser Control - JSON undefine error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381393/vb6-webbrowser-control-json-undefine-error)

Answer (score 1):

You are embedding Web Browser in Win Forms project... and the browser engine is probably IE8 - it doesn't have JSON variable used by script. You need to define JSON parser yourself - take a look at this Q&A for more info:

[JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8)